# SQL script running in SQL server fine but when executes through Job it is failing?

Tags: sql-server

I have used script in SQL server which is working fine. But when used the same in SSIS package and executes through sql server agent job it is failing

Error message is Description: Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction. DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

I have tried in Google about the error but no luck in fixing the error. please anyone suggest me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear...

This fails

```
Begin tran
backup database name to disk=somedisk

Commit
```

with error:

> Msg 3021, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Onto why your job is failing in SSIS,check the [Transaction property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15) of the container or the package..it should be not supported based on parent containers

also [Docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/set-package-properties?view=sql-server-ver15)..

> The value of the IsolationLevel property requested by the container is respected only when the container initiates a new transaction. A container initiates a new transaction when the following conditions are true:
> **The value of the container's TransactionOption property is Required**

Also i don't see any reason,why you need Isolation level property for Backup Tasks..

Comment: Thanks. so, do I need to change Transaction Property Isolation Level to Serializable and Transaction Option is Not Supported. Is that correct?

Comment: @Amelia:see updated,i would go with default(Serializable),as your isolation level requested would be ignored,unless you specify a transaction

Comment: I have used default Serializable with Transaction Option as Not Supported. But still getting same error. Do I need to change anything?

Comment: Try using other basic isolation leve

Comment: through job it is failing but when I execute package manually it is working. I am not getting what is the problem with job.